# Julia - Understanding LinearMaps example

Tags: julia

I am trying to wrap my head around the `LinearMaps.jl` package. In their [documentation](https://jutho.github.io/LinearMaps.jl/dev/#Examples) they have only two examples and I am stuck at the first one.

```
# Define a linear map from a matrix and one from a function (?)
A = LinearMap(rand(10, 10))
B = LinearMap(cumsum, reverse∘cumsum∘reverse, 10)
# Possible operations
3.0A + 2B
A + I
A*B'
[A B; B A]
kron(A, B)
```

How does `LinearMap()` work when its argument(s) are functions? For instance the `cumsum()` function doesn't work on its own as it requires the `dims` argument, so I am completely puzzled as to what this is doing.

Comment: My understanding is that a linear map is a function with the property that `f(ax + by) = af(x) + bf(y)`. Clearly a matrix satisfies this condition, so `LinearMap(rand(10, 10))` makes sense to me, it's probably just a different representation of the matrix. But how about `B`?

Comment: I think the method that we are using there is `LinearMap{T=Float64}(f, [fc,], M::Int, N::Int = M; kwargs...)::FunctionMap` given [here](https://jutho.github.io/LinearMaps.jl/dev/types/).

I understand that `M=10` and by default `N=M=10`. Now in this case `f=cumsum` and is supposed to take in vectors of size `N` and return vectors of size `M` but surely this is not the case? Also which vectors are we talking about?

Comment: Oh actually `cumsum()` does take in a vector of length `N=10` and return a vector of length `M=10`..

Comment: One thing I have noticed is that this behaves as expected `Matrix(LinearMap(x->x, 3))` gives the `3x3` identity matrix and `Matrix(LinearMap(x->2x, 3))` gives `2I`.

Comment: I'm getting closer. Consider `x = [1, 2, 3]`. Then the linear map `B = LinearMap(cumsum, reverse∘cumsum∘reverse, 3)` essentially does `cumsum(x)` as can be seen by running `B*x`.

Comment: Ah! The cumsum function can be represented by a lower-triangular matrix
```
B =(1 0 0 )
      (1 1 0)
      (1 1 1)
```
and this can be found by running `Matrix(B)`. Multiplying this matrix by `x = (x1, x2, x3)` indeed gives `(x1, x1+x2, x1+x2+x3)`. Now, the transpose of `B` is given by
```
B' = (1 1 1)
       (0 1 1)
       (0 0 1)
```
and multiplying `B'x` we get `(x1+x2+x3, x2+x3, x3)`. Now to compute this one can do ``reverse(cumsum(reverse(x)))` since `reverse(x)=(x3, x2, x1)` and `cumsum(reverse(x))=(x3, x3+x2, x3+x2+1)`.

Comment: You probably know this already, but just to comment on the general concept: Julia treats functions like any other instances, it's very common to pass functions into type constructors or other functions, and it's only a bit more unusual to return functions. As you have observed in this case, the function `cumsum` by itself cannot specify what it will do (you need both function and arguments in order to dispatch to a method), but `LinearMap`'s fields and its methods get the necessary arguments for `cumsum`.